# Redirecting to other url in Pyramid?

Tags: python, post, redirect, pyramid, pylons

I am laying down a 2 way SMS service.

User will be sending an SMS to a virtual number provided by SMS server platform (www.sms.com). That SMS server platform will pass on user SMS data to my my url (http://www.yourdomainname.com/ReceiveSMS?from=from&message=message)

Now I process user request based on the "message" and then I need to post reply to this url
(www.sms.com/optin.php?user=username&pass=password&to=to_mobile_number&message=dynamic_message)

My question is how do I post it to url www.sms.com/optin.php?user=username&pass=password&to=to_mobile_number&message=dynamic_message after processing.

One way I thought of doing was using HTTPFound.

Wanted to know if there is a more efficient way?

Comment: Your terminology is difficult to parse. Do you need to redirect the user to that url, or do you need to talk to that url in the background? You cannot "post" in a redirect so what you are asking is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

in pyramid views, you can return a [webob](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id4) response to side step any renderer logic. So for a redirect you set a status of [301/302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and the [location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

```
from webob import Response

@view_config(...)
def your_view(context, request):
    # do stuff
    return Response(status_int=302, location="http://goherenext.com")
```

[HTTPFound](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#using-a-view-callable-to-do-an-http-redirect) is just a subclass of the response with the [status hard-coded](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/httpexceptions.py#L474).

Answer (score 0):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) is really nice for sending POST requests

```
>>> message = 'hello!' # From your inbound SMS
>>> data = {
    'user': 'username', 
    'pass': 'password', 
    'message': message, 
    'to': '123456789'
}
>>> r = requests.post("www.sms.com/optin.php", params=data)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for answering my question. But here the request from SMS server will be coming to my view and after view has processed the request, response will be going to "www.sms.com/optin.php". Just not sure how to do it with Pyramid